# The related questions on sidebar are displaying links instead of Question titles

Tags: bug, status-norepro, related-questions, encoding, internet-explorer-8

As specified in the title, related questions sometimes have links instead of their respective question titles.

[image: Link to the screenshot]

([This is the question where that screenshot was taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439057/eclipse-imported-a-project-and-eclipse-is-giving-me-wrong-override-method-ann))

This issue is identified in IE 8.

Comment: You could at least post a link to an image so someone can edit it in for you...

Comment: Upload to http://imgur.com and post link or just tell where you see that happening, can't reproduce.

Comment: Can't reproduce, this is the exact question from the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439057/eclipse-imported-a-project-and-eclipse-is-giving-me-wrong-override-method-ann/9439084#9439084

Comment: The issue is as per the current screenshot updated by @Shog9

Comment: Three-dimensional freehand circles.  Most impressive.

Comment: This issue is identified in IE8 but not replicated in Chrome.

Comment: Could it be that your using Internet Explorer? Oooh! Oooh! An extension! Yes! An extension!